# VmWare Workstation 10 How to make OS X maverick guest connect to my wireless network?

Tags: networking, macos, windows-8.1, vmware-workstation

I am trying to work with OS X Maverick using VmWare Worsktation 10.0.1 on a host machine that runs Windows 8.1. So far everything is working fine except for the network, i cannot make the guest machine to connect to the internet (i can't activate any of the software am using there and can't even download xCode).

Based on the reasearch that i've done, it seems that i have to share my network adapter from win8 with Vmware which i already did, but then i have to make sure that there is no IP conflict or something, which is something that i don't know how to make, can anyone please suggest a solution ?

PS:
I can only try wireless network now, i don't have direct access to the router.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert all settings you have tried and all you need to do is, make your guest operating system Network Adapter settings as 'NAT' mode connection which is usually share host machine IP address. Follow the steps:

Click VM > Settings > Hardware tab > Network > now, select 'NAT' connection on the right pane of the window. Now power on the guest virtual machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, these seems to work, now i have the "network icon" on bottom right with green dot, but on OS X i have no sign of wifi or a network but when i go to Utilities->airPort Utility, the Internet  switch randomly between Connected/disconnected. and the strange part is that my Wifi on Windows8 also turn itself on/off randomly

Comment: Your OSX install shows no WiFi since it knows of no WiFi. It only sees a virtual network card.